# Can I create folders

Tags: file-management

I have a Samsung Galaxy s6 with Nougat.

When I connect,with cable,my phone to the pc in the window I can see "folders",on

the phone I can't (archive>documents).

How can I see or create folders on my phone?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of file managers available [on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file%20manager&c=apps). Simply select your favorite and you will be able to see the folders on your phone, from your phone.